# Dynamically pivot or spread my columns into rows without having to specify the number of columns

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | Header 1 | Header 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | AA |
| 1 | 123 | BB |
| 2 | 000 | CC |
| 2 | 000 | EE |
| 2 | 000 | YY |
| 3 | 345 | DD |
| 3 | 345 | NN |

I would like to pivot/spread the table wider so that each ID number will have one row by spreading the values in "Header 2":

| ID | Header 1 | New Col1 | New Col2 | New Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | AA | BB | *null* |
| 2 | 000 | CC | EE | YY |
| 3 | 345 | DD | NN | *null* |

I tried the `pivot` function in SQL but my biggest issue is that each ID number may have different number of observations in Header 2 (some might have 2 others might have 3-4) so I can't pre-specify the number of column headers to pivot for. Also I don't want to aggregate the values given it is text so not sure how to get around that if I use `pivot` in SQL.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to build the pivot query using a select statement against information_schema.columns or however you can get the column list, then run an execute statement to run the query. You can insert data from an execute into a table.